# interaction failed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, interaction

my buttons are working fine but its still giving me "interaction failed issue"

```
class StartButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user_id, cog, channel):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.cog = cog
        self.channel = channel

    @discord.ui.button(label='Hit', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id='hit')
    async def hit(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user_id = self.user_id
        await self.cog.hit(interaction, user_id, self.channel)

->** another class starts**

    async def hit(self, interaction, user_id, channel):
        if user_id not in self.players:
            await channel.send("You haven't started the game yet. Use `!start`.")
            return
         _some extra code, cant post cuz too much code_
```

**i tried putting interaction.response.defer() in it, but still getting same issue**

Comment: Are you properly responding to the interaction at all?

Comment: yeah, just figured out the issue lol,

its (self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button)

and not (self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction) like i wrote above, feels dumb man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out, something minor took so much of my time:

it's not

```
async def hit(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
```

the correct form is:

```
async def hit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
```

And ofcourse add interaction.response.defer() or the other one, check documentation